# contextual action mode vs. floating menu

Tags: android, android-actionbar

According to this page: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html#context-menu, Contextual Action Mode is preferred when working on Honeycomb or higher. This is actually very useful when you can apply the same kind of action to several items at a time (eg: delete).
But some actions actually only make sense on one item at a time (eg: Edit).
If you have only one of these actions, well, you can simply use the single click for it. So: One click = edit and select multiple items = action mode with actions that apply to many items

An example of that is the Gmail app: one click = read the email and selecting many items, you can mark them as read, delete them, etc.

OK, but what if you have multiple actions that can only a apply to one item at a time? Imagine the following situation.

You have a list of profiles.You can do the following actions on the profiles:

- delete
- export (save in a file)
- share

These actions could be applied to many items at a time, so you place them in the action mode. But other actions could be:

- edit
- apply

You can only edit or apply one profile at a time.

So, in that case, is it OK to continue using floating menus like this:

One single click or long-click opens a floating menu with available options on that particular item alone (edit, apply, delete, export, share).
Selecting multiple items activates the action mode with actions that apply to all the selected items (delete, export, share)

Or maybe is it better to keep using action mode only?

When one item is selected, all actions are available (edit, apply, delete, export, share)
When more than one item are selected, the actions edit and apply are disabled/removed from the action bar.

Both methods can work of course and it could be up to the developer to choose but what would be best practice or the best approach to be more user-friendly?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

In GMail, you can also star as well as read on clicking on one item.  This is achieved by putting buttons into each row (a star).

Comment: Right! I also thought about that and forgot to talk about it. Well, in my case, I already have several views in my custom item views. On the left, I have the checkbox and on the right, a handle to allow the user to sort the items. In the middle, the name of the item + a few visual codes (icons). I'm not sure some more Views would fit there, especially on small screens and I don't want to overload the item's views either. Also, there could be several "one-item-actions" and I would have to put a button for each one...

Comment: @BenoîtBouré - it sounds like you might need to simplify it a little... http://www.appway.com/screen/blog_entry_permalink/language/en/blog_entry_id/1211750923026

Comment: This is exactly what I don't Want to do. I already have enough stuff in my views and don't want to add more. So far, my item views look a bit like the gmail app replacing the star with a "sorter". The icons I'm talking about are more like the priority icon. Anyway, this is not the question. Thanks for your time anyway.